# I wanna semi-transparent video at Video play time

Tags: c#

I am using Windows Media Player control in C# and I want a semi-transparent video at video play time. I set `Opacity` to `0.5` in my form. It is semi-transparent in `Windows 7` but it isn't  translucent in `Windows XP`. Please tell me the illustrates how it is done at Windows XP? I use the development environment `Visual Studio 2008` `.Net framework 2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The translucency is done using windows 7's [Aero](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/aero.aspx) (available since windows vista). This won't be possible in windows xp

Comment: There's a limit to what you can do in XP. Can I ask why you are required to support a really old OS? Any chance the user can just update to a more recent OS such as vista or win7?

Comment: @JoelMartinez Upgrading it **Costs Money** and some people **prefer older operating systems** or don't want to learn a new one. Why spend the money when it works just fine, and if you are selling software, you need to support at least XP.

Comment: I both agree, and disagree with you. On the one hand, yes, if there's a significant userbase then it would behoove you to support it. But at the same time, if developers keep supporting those old systems, then users will never have a reason to upgrade. It's the same as webdevs supporting IE6 ... unless their web experience starts to break and no longer work, they will never upgrade to a newer (and easier to program against) computing experience.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far I know, having per-pixel alpha window in WinXP is possible,
you have to google about WS_EX_LAYERED, UpdateLayeredWindow with AC_SRC_ALPHA.
However that means you need to write your own code for rendering process and that's quite complicated(to make efficiently)

Alternative solution would be to use WPF, all you have to do is:

```
<Window AllowTransparency="True" Opacity="0.5"><MediaElement Source="yourfile.wmv" /></Window>
```

and it should work.